# what to do when monitor does not have edid information?

Tags: xorg, display-resolution

I have a TV screen that does not have any edid information.. not even windows get any information from it..

The HDTV's brand is `SANSUI` and it's model is `sled2453w` in case you would want to check on it

so for this my nvidia drivers fails to detect the available resolution for this and i cannot get out of 1024x768..

i have tried the methods of editing `xorg.conf` but no work, even adding modes in xrandr.. so how can i fix this without having to buy a new screen monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue with one of my monitors.  It would not pull the `EDID` from the monitor at all.  I had to manually add the refresh and sync info to my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

One way that I know of to get the `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` for your monitor (HDTV) is to run the `nvidia-xconfig`.  Don't run the application with your existing `xorg.conf` file, as it might pull incorrect information.

I got my info by running the following:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -c /dev/null -o xconfig_mine.conf
```

This created a file called `xconfig_mine.conf` in the directory I was working in.  Contained in that file was the following information:  (it might be different for your configuration but the Unknown VendorName and ModelName should be there)

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

The above info is that for my monitor that it cannot detect properly.

I copied that info, and I added it to my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file above the `Section "Screen"` part.  After that was added, I rebooted my system, then my `xrandr` application was able to see all sorts of resolutions that my monitor supports (even ones that it doesn't support).  So, after adding that info, I was then able to get my monitor to max at the resolution of `1280x1024` which it does support.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your method. But it doesnt work for me.. at this time i dont have xorg.conf because when i use it, the only resolution i get is 640x480. And the c parameter throws an error saying xorg-server is not found. Also the code it outputs is the same as the normal xorg.conf. so problem still the same

Comment: @nosthertus Do you have an NVIDIA card installed on your system?  And do you have the `xserver-xorg` installed?

Comment: Yes its nvidia but im not sure if i have xorg-server. I cant do a check now because im not close to the machne at the moment. If it helps i installed nvidia drivers through update software and update in the system configuration

Comment: @nosthertus Make sure that you install the `xserver-xorg` when you are near your system.  I just checked mine, and I definitely have that installed which is what controls the xorg-server.  `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg`

Comment: Just wait 3hrs until i get out from the university

Comment: @nosthertus Take your time.  I'm in no hurry.  :)

Comment: I came back and it seems `xserver-xorg` is installed but i cannot run it through terminal

Comment: @nosthertus When the file was created from the `sudo nvidia-xconfig -c /dev/null -o xconfig_mine.conf` command, what did the Monitor section with the "Unknown" names show?

Comment: terminal prompts an error saying `Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.`, but the monitor section shows unknown value to `vendorName` and `modelName` properties

Comment: we could talk through chat if you wish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38048/discussion-between-terrance-and-nosthertus).

Comment: i will try that

Comment: mini-hdmi method failed